# nant script c# compilation error

Tags: c#, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Unfortunately my knowledge of NANT stuff is very limited but embarked today on updating our build to run some code.  We use cruisecontrol.

This works fine - however I need to process two folders so was trying to put common code into a traditional c# method.

```
<echo message="Ensure only 4 directories in the backup directory"/>
    <script language="C#">
      <code>
        <![CDATA[
  public static void ScriptMain(Project project)
  {
      string path = project.Properties["build.ReleasesShareLocation.BackupParent"];
      string [] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path,"*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

      System.Collections.ArrayList dirlist = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
      foreach (string folder in folders)
      {
          dirlist.Add(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folder));
      }
      dirlist.Sort(new DirectoryInfoDateComparer());
      dirlist.Reverse();

      for (int i = 4; i < dirlist.Count; i++)
      {
          string foldername = ((System.IO.DirectoryInfo)dirlist[i]).Name;
          try
          {
              ((System.IO.DirectoryInfo)dirlist[i]).Delete(true);
              project.Log(Level.Info, String.Format("Deleted folder {0}", foldername));

          }
          catch { project.Log(Level.Warning, String.Format("Unable to delete folder {0}", foldername)); }
      }
  }

    internal class DirectoryInfoDateComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di1 = (System.IO.DirectoryInfo)x;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di2 = (System.IO.DirectoryInfo)y;

            return di1.CreationTime.CompareTo(di2.CreationTime);
        }
    }
    ]]>
      </code>
    </script>
```

Rather than repeat all the code - I tried to add a static class with a method to do all the processing so that the main only passes the two paths.  But in running the build on the server (is there a way for me to "compile" this locally??) it errored.

This is the code that errored - I'm not sure if I've missed a simple syntax error (I did try to copy and paste the code in visual studio to make sure the brackets and stuff matched up) or if there is a different way I need to do it in NANT build..

```
<echo message="Ensure only 4 directories in the backup directory"/>
    <script language="C#">
      <code>
        <![CDATA[
  public static void ScriptMain(Project project)
  {
      string path = project.Properties["build.ReleasesShareLocation.BackupParent"];
      string path2 = project.Properties["build.DeltaScriptFileShareLocation.BackupParent"];
      Processor.ProcessFolder(path);
      Processor.ProcessFolder(path2);
  }

internal static class Processor
{
    public static void ProcessFolder(string path)
    {
        string [] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path,"*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        System.Collections.ArrayList dirlist = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            dirlist.Add(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folder));
        }
        dirlist.Sort(new DirectoryInfoDateComparer());
        dirlist.Reverse();

        for (int i = 4; i < dirlist.Count; i++)
        {
            string foldername = ((System.IO.DirectoryInfo)dirlist[i]).Name;
            try
            {
                ((System.IO.DirectoryInfo)dirlist[i]).Delete(true);
                project.Log(Level.Info, String.Format("Deleted folder {0}", foldername));

            }
            catch { project.Log(Level.Warning, String.Format("Unable to delete folder {0}", foldername)); }
        }
    }
}

    internal class DirectoryInfoDateComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di1 = (System.IO.DirectoryInfo)x;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di2 = (System.IO.DirectoryInfo)y;

            return di1.CreationTime.CompareTo(di2.CreationTime);
        }
    }
    ]]>
      </code>
    </script>
```

Thanks for any assistance :)

---

Edit:

I went back through the CC logs and re-read the error message - this time understanding what it was trying to tell me.  Turns out I needed to pass my new method the Project parameter. :)

Is there a way to be able to compile the code without having to run a build to find errors like this?  I tried pasting it into Visual Studio but as I didn't have the Nant library referenced it wasn't highlighting the error effectively.  Or is there something you can download and install on a dev machine to reference appropriate dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In re-reading the error logs I found within the wall of red text the answer.

Turns out I needed to pass my new method the Project parameter (as I was referring to Project properties).

So problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Go to command prompt, navigate to the folder where you installed NANT, and type in your NANT build command manually, for example:

```
 nant -f:MyBuildFile.build
```

That way you'll see the errors, and we can help further.

Comment: Is this different to running it from cctray?  (or were you suggesting this was how I could test it locally? though I only have nant installed on the server)

Comment: Nant has really a straightforward and really simple installation (basically, just copying the bins to a folder), I don't see why you wouldn't install it on client for debugging purposes. It's a command prompt tool, you don't have to reference it from visual studio, but run it in cmd and see the errors as they appear (the other way is to look at the logs of the build server, but people tend not to do that :))

Comment: And to answer: no, I don't expect it to be different than cctray (I haven't checked but the cctray probably runs it with some additional parameters to redirect to it's custom log, but nothing that impacts the way of execution)

Comment: Cool will look at downloading it locally - I then need to figure out what version we have on the server (if that matters).  As the dev environment was set up for me locally (without Nant) I haven't had to worry about adding anything.  I'd still prefer to be able to "compile" my code to find syntax errors without having to run the build.  Mainly because the current build logs so many (irrelevant) errors it can sometimes be tricky to find the newly introduced ones. :) Thanks for your help!